# Function produces expected type "String", did you mean to call it with "()"

Tags: ios, swift

```
let documentUrl: NSURL? = {
    return NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first
}

var test: String = {
    return "String"
}
```

This is a very simple piece of code, but there is an error from Xcode, asked me to add () at the end of the computed property, like this:

```
let documentUrl: NSURL? = {
        return NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first
    }()

var test: String = {
            return "String"
        }()
```

Who can tell me why?

Answer (score 14):

You wrote this:

```
var test: String = {
    return "String"
}
```

That is *not* a computed property. You are initializing your variable `test` to a function body (an anonymous function, sometimes called a closure). That isn't what you mean to do. You want to *call* the function and set the variable `test` to the *result*. The parentheses make that happen; that is how you *call* a function. Thus:

```
var test: String = {
    return "String"
}()
```

Thus you define the function and call it, all in one move, and assign the result as the initial value of `test`.

If you wanted a computed property, you should have written it like this:

```
var test: String {
    return "String"
}
```

Notice there is no equal sign. A fuller form would be:

```
var test: String {
    get {
        return "String"
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I just realize it when I post this Question, the computed property should be looks like "var test: String {
            return "String"
        }()", Thank you very much for you answer