# In a variable or constant declaration set to a closure with '()' at the end, is the closure executed each time the variable is accessed?

Tags: swift

In the following code in Swift, is the closure executed each time the variable 'integer' is called, or just when the variable is declared?

```
let integer: Int = {
    return 1
}()
```

Anyone know what that () is called? When I leave it out, there is a code time error that tells what the error is, but it refers to () simply as '()', and does not tell me what that's called or what Apple calls what '()' does when put where it is in my sample code above.

> Function produces expected type 'Int'; did you mean to call it with '()'?

The following code is where I use () in actual code intended for production, if anyone wants to know:

```
var sharableZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: DatabaseNameStrings.recordZoneName, ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)

var userRecordID: CKRecord.ID? = {
    
    var localUserRecordID: CKRecord.ID? = nil
    
    containerCourier.fetchUserRecordID() {
        
        (recordID: CKRecord.ID?, error: Error?) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        if let recordID = recordID {
            localUserRecordID = recordID
            sharableZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: DatabaseNameStrings.recordZoneName, ownerName: recordID.zoneID.ownerName)
        } else {
            print("couldn't get current user record id")
        }
        
    }

    return localUserRecordID
    
}()
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36749295/1187415

Comment: For more info on computed variables and let closures, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626675/is-is-complusory-to-use-in-keyword-in-closure-if-no-then-what-is-the-differen/71626825#71626825). To see *when* they are called, you can add a `print()` command in the closure and check the console.

Comment: Please read [Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID232) in the Swift Language Guide.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make it a computed property not a closure

```
var sharableZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: DatabaseNameStrings.recordZoneName, ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)

var userRecordID:CKRecord.ID? = {
    
    var localUserRecordID: CKRecord.ID? = nil
    
    containerCourier.fetchUserRecordID() {
        
        (recordID: CKRecord.ID?, error: Error?) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        if let recordID = recordID {
            localUserRecordID = recordID
            sharableZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: DatabaseNameStrings.recordZoneName, ownerName: recordID.zoneID.ownerName)
        } else {
            print("couldn't get current user record id")
        }
        
    }

    return localUserRecordID
    
}
```

Second the call `containerCourier.fetchUserRecordID() {` is asynchronous so this computing property will always return nil   , so you need to make it like this

```
func getId(completion:@escaping((CKRecord.ID?) ->()))  {
    
    var sharableZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: DatabaseNameStrings.recordZoneName, ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)
   
    containerCourier.fetchUserRecordID() {
        
        (recordID: CKRecord.ID?, error: Error?) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
        
        if let recordID = recordID { 
            sharableZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: DatabaseNameStrings.recordZoneName, ownerName: recordID.zoneID.ownerName)
            completion(recordID)
        } else {
            print("couldn't get current user record id")
            completion(nil)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```